# Query para crear distintas columnas utilizando la funcion SUM()

Tags: sql

Tengo una base parecida a esta:

```
| Fecha     | Tipo   | Monto   |
|:--------- |:------:| -------:|
|    5/12   | 1      | 5000    |
|    5/12   | 2      | 3000    |
|    6/12   | 3      | 7000    |
|    6/12   | 1      | 4000    |
```

Lo que estaría necesitando es crear una query que me de como resultado una tabla con cuatro columnas fecha, y una para la suma de cada tipo.

Algo parecido al sumar.si de excel seria, agrupar por fecha la suma de cada tipo

Comment: Por favor es necesario que puedas colocar lo que hayas intentado y algún error específico en el que te podamos ayudar. Te recomiendo también que leas la guía de como hacer preguntas. Saludos

Comment: Saludos @AgustinCerdan, como bien te dice **nicP** debes agregar lo que has intentado, por favor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así ganar tu primera medalla. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es un agregado condicional. Muchas veces se olvida que lo que va dentro de `SUM()` no es una columna sino una expresión. Eso permite que puedas incluir constantes, columnas y cosas más complejas.

```
SELECT Fecha,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Tipo = 1 THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS MontoTipo1,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Tipo = 2 THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS MontoTipo2,
        SUM( CASE WHEN Tipo = 3 THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS MontoTipo3
FROM MiTabla
GROUP BY Fecha;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! No conocia ese uso de SUM()!!!

Answer (score 0):

Espero haber entendido lo que pedis...
Suponiendo que tenemos la siguiente tabla "productos":
[image: Estructura de la tabla]

La cual contiene los siguientes registros almacenados:

[image: Registros de la tabla "productos"]

Hacemos uso de la query:

```sql
select fecha,tipo,sum(monto) as monto_por_tipo from productos group by tipo;
```

Obteniendo la siguiente tabla como resultado:

[image: Resultado de la query]

Ojala te sirva, ya que no creo haber entendido bien lo que necesitas.